# Setting up SSH connection on VSTS to remotely copy files from bitbucket to remote machine

Tags: git, ssh, azure-pipelines

I need to set up a SSH connection endpoint in order to add task to remotely copy files from repository to remote machine. [image]

I have the following information,

- IP
- user
- password
- passphrase
- .ppk private_key file

I have added the required information and contents of .ppk file in endpoint fields but I get the error: Timed out while waiting for handshake.. (When I enter passphrase)
error:  Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format.(When I enter password)

What am I doing wrong here?
Am using VSTS2015

Comment: What's the result if you use ssh private key `id_rsa` instead of puttygen private key `.ppk`?

Answer (score 0):

For SSH service endpoint, please **try to use ssh private key `id_rsa` instead**.

To generate ssh key, you can use `ssh-keygen`, select path and enter passphrase for the ssh key. After that, you can find `id_rsa` file in `.ssh` folder. Copy the content of `id_rsa` as Private key in ssh end point.

Beside for copying files from bitbucket to remote machine, you can use **Windows machine file cop**y task directly. In a build definition:

**Get sources:** select Rempte repo -> set bitbucket repo as the url -> input your user name and password for bitbucket.[image]

**Windows Machine File Copy:** the Admin Login should be `ComputerName\UserName`.

[image]